# What do you call it, when someone is only selfish/egoistical to a specific person

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call it when a person will not let you do the things you have to do? Will not let you live your life?

I am not talking about law or the 10 commandments, or a figure of authority. Could be someone the same age, older or younger. I am talking about someone who prevents you from living your life, a normal life, by suffocating, bullying, slandering, and sabotaging it. Someone who will hinder things unnecessarily. But on the other hand, that same person is allowed to do everything.

For example, someone who suffocates your life, bullies you, gets angry just because you are pretty (even if the person is prettier), only he/she can be pretty, or they are envious (maybe you can play keyboard well for example), but only he/she can have a talent or ability, and does everything to humiliate you in order to isolate you from anyone while only he/she is allowed to live how/where/whatever they are supposed to.

To illustrate better what I am describing, I'll talk about my own experience. There are even some people who didn't/don't allow me to be a female. They tried to turn me into the opposite sex, tried to turn me into a male. There was a time I could not be feminine, use makeup or fancy any guy because of this. I ended up acting tomboyish and meek and plain to avoid some people's rage, even when I wanted to be feminine. Whereas the same girls had girlfriends prettier than me who were allowed to be feminine and remain friends. If I tried to be feminine they would intimidate me or humiliate me, even worse if I started having a crush on a guy they didn't like. Only they can be feminine, only they can have a crush on a guy/date, have friends, etc.

There was a time I was going through hunger, and the people who told me not to eat anything were every day eating the best of everything.

All those people were selfish JUST TO ME, without reason (yes without reason). What is it called?

Comment: Hm by "There was a time I was going through hunger, and the people who told me not to eat anything were everyday eating the best of everything" I don't mean I wanted them to share their food with me , I mean they told me  and reinforced I was not supposed to eat unless something disgusting or poisonous

Comment: Isn't that person a control freak? Sometimes moving away is a way to start fresh.  What you describe is far from the social norm in the US.

Comment: The word is *target*.  These people have *targeted* you for their abuse.

Comment: "But on the other hand, that same person is allowed to do everything. " This specific behavior is called **hypocrisy** (and the person who behaves this way is a **hypocrite**)

Answer (score 2):

When I first started reading, the word narcissistic came to mind.  However, as I read all the way to the end, I believe you are being abused and need to get out of that situation as soon as possible. Most cities and towns (unless you're in a very rural area) have women's shelters where you can go for protection and to start an independent life-free from your abusers.  Any hospital will help you and most places of worship will help you get into a shelter too.  Please let me know if you aren't sure where to begin and I will be glad to help you get started. You deserve a better life.